# Excel Pivot Table Group by Date

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have pivot table that I am trying to group by date. When I tried to group by date, it creates an attribute called Group1. For some reason Excel wont allow me to group by Date. What am i doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Make sure **every** date in your raw data is an actual date. It only takes **one** string in data to make the groupings not work for a pivot. You can look up how to verify if a value is a valid date online

Comment: @urdearboy I have valid dates. There are no blanks, sprints or special characters.

Comment: Right click on a single cell in pivot with date and then select Group. Should give you date options

Answer (score 0):

I used the "Clear Format" function in the ribbons. Then I formatted the cell as "Date". After I did this, it the group function in the pivot table worked just fine.

Maybe there was a special formatting in my data set when I downloaded it.